# Data move to historical table whenever new data with same key appear during 2nd load In SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

i am struggling how i can design this. appreciate your suggestion.

**We are loading data using SSIS ETL Package.**

I have 2 tables Active and History.

When we load the active table historical table will remain empty. 
when we will load data have same (comp_id+SKU+COMP_SKU) the older data need to move to historical table old data move to history table.

**my idea is to used Trigger.would like to know your valuable suggestion.**

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE ACTIVE

(
COMP_ID INT ,
SKU INT,
COMP_SKU VARCHAR (100),
PRICE_INCVAT FLOAT,
[ValidFrom]     DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
[TODT]       DATETIME DEFAULT ('12/31/9999') 

)

SELECT * FROM ACTIVE

INSERT INTO ACTIVE (COMP_ID,SKU,COMP_SKU,PRICE_INCVAT,VALIDITY_DATE)
VALUES ('1001', '101110048',    '642BM0045',    '47.45',    '12/26/2016  5:04:00 AM')

INSERT INTO ACTIVE (COMP_ID,SKU,COMP_SKU,PRICE_INCVAT,VALIDITY_DATE)
VALUES ('1001', '101110046',    '642BM0040',    '35.14',    '12/26/2016  5:04:00 AM')
When we will do 2nd load like given below

/*
2nd load data

1001    101110046   642BM0040   65.52   6/26/2016 5:04  31/12/9999
1001    101110048   642BM0045   47.45   6/26/2016 8:04  31/12/9999
*/

after 2nd load history table will look like given below

/*
HISTORY TABLE

COMP_ID PNO COMP_PNO1   PRICE_INCVAT    Validity_date   TODT
1001    101110046   642BM0040   35.14   12/26/2016 5:04 **6/26/2016 5:04**
1001    101110048   642BM0045   47.45   12/26/2016 5:04 **6/26/2016 8:04**

*/
```

Please help me to design this.

Comment: which is better, moving match record (based on key) to seperate table or retain in same table with flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the **reason you are holding historical data for facts.**

If the reason is:

- For reporting needs then you could hold it in the same table by
  adding two date columns `FromDate` and `ToDate` which will remove the
  need to join the active and historical data tables later on.
- Just for reference then it makes sense to have it in a different
  table as it may decrease the performance of your indexes on your
  active table.

**EDIT:** OP has requested inputs on how to implement the whole process.

I'll highlight the Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) type 2 approach that tracks data history by maintaining multiple versions of records and uses either the `EndDate` or a flag to identify the active record. This method allows tracking any number of historical records as each time a new record is inserted, the older ones are populated with an `EndDate`.

**Step 1:** For re-loaded facts `UPDATE` `IsActive = 0` for the record to be history preserved and populate `EndDate` as the current date.

```
merge ActiveTable as T
using DataToBeLoaded as D  
    on  T.Comp_ID = D.Comp_ID
      and T.SKU = D.SKU
        and T.Comp_SKU = D.Comp_SKU
         and T.isactive = 1  -- Current active entry
  when matched then
    update set T.IsActive = 0,
               T.EndDate = GETDATE();
```

**Step 2:** Insert the latest data into the ActiveTable with `IsActive = 1` and `FromDate` as the current date.

**Disclaimer:** The following approach using SCD 2 could make your data warehouse huge.

Comment: Thanks a lot . kindly share if you have any script  by adding two date columns FromDate and ToDate.

Comment: Just `ALTER TABLE` to add these columns? Or do you want to know how to implement the whole process with these two added columns?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can guide me o know how to implement the whole process ... Thanks a lot